# R: extra randomness in randomForest?

Tags: r

I used `randomForest` method from package "randomForest" on a training data set to see how it is related to the regression tree method provided in the "tree" package, just out of curiosity. Here is the command:

```
rf.fit = randomForest(formula, data = dataTrain, mtry = var, ntree = 1,
                      replace = FALSE, samplesize = nrow(dataTrain))
```

where `var` is the number of variables in the formula. Since all variables were adopted, the sampling was carried out without replacement on the full training data set, I thought the prediction on a test data set of the output model `rf.fit` should be consistent and equal to that from the tree method. However it changed from round to round if no seed was set and was different from latter method. I am confused where the extra randomness comes from.

Comment: I tested `randomForest` with the `iris` data set and it *does* produce a different prediction each time, even with `mtry` equal to the number of predictor variables (4 in this case), `samplesize=nrow(iris)` and the other parameters as you specified.

Answer (score 1):

The two algorithms you're comparing use different splitting criteria so I wouldn't expect the predictive results to be identical even if you weren't facing "randomness" as you say.

You probably should spend some time reading up on the algorithms being employed (see descriptive works by [Breiman (2001)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324) and the R implementation by [Liaw and Wiener (2002)](http://cogns.northwestern.edu/cbmg/LiawAndWiener2002.pdf)). The "randomness" is introduced because for each tree generated by the Random Forests algorithm there is a random subsample of 1/3 of the sample withheld for out-of-bag error estimation. Therefore, the tree is only being estimated on the other 2/3 of your data, which will change from run to run unless you `set.seed()` first.

You can check which observations are used in OOB estimates in the fit object:
`rf.fit$oob.times`